# Qsort in an iteration?

Tags: c

I have an iteration like that in C:

```
if (streetList->street[y]->cityStart == s->cityId &&
    streetList->street[y]->cityEnd == sl->city[z]->cityId ||
    streetList->street[y]->cityEnd == s->cityId &&
    streetList->street[y]->cityStart == sl->city[z]->cityId) {
  printf("%d %s\n", streetList->street[y]->distance, sl->city[z]->name);
}
```

Both lists are coming from two different .dat files that I read in automatically.

The code above prints out the the CityName and its distance to a city that was set by the user. This all works fine.

However, I would like to quickly sort that output by the distance (which is an integer). Is there a way to do that in C inside the iteration? For example, I would like to sort that output so that I get first the city with the lowest distance to the given city in the iteration.

For example:

```
350, New York
200, Miami
```

should become

```
200 Miami
350 New York
```

I read about `qsort`, but I'm not quite sure how to use it properly in my example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Function `qsort` cannot sort two arrays in parallel. Build a new array of `struct` with pointers to the required data and sort that.

Comment: Would it be possible just to sort the distance in streetlist?

Comment: The loop is printing data from two different sources. Anyway, if you try sorting the data before you have finished the comparisons, that will go haywire.

Comment: Yea i know, but i don't want to tangle to much with the information as i need to output later all data again. I have an idea and i think it should work. I add a new integer distance to the city structure and just add the distance when there is a match and then sort that quickly by checking if the distance is not null. Since this program sorts only once per execution, this should work. I'll see and report back if there are problems with the qsort or something. Thanks for taking your time by the way.

Comment: @WeatherVane is there a way to qsort the attribute of an array? Like: sl->city[z]->distance ? all my cities have now a distance, either 0 or a given distance. it should work to sort now the list by the distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution on my own and i just want to share it in case anybody else runs into this issue.

What i did is i added to my city structure a distance integer. I assigned the distance from the street to the city. If there is no matching street, than the distance will be just set to 0.

```
if (streetList->street[y]->cityStart == s->cityId &&
    streetList->street[y]->cityEnd == sl->city[z]->cityId ||
    streetList->street[y]->cityEnd == s->cityId &&
    streetList->street[y]->cityStart == sl->city[z]->cityId) {
  printf("%d %s\n", streetList->street[y]->distance, sl->city[z]->name);
  sl->city[z]->distance = streetList->street[y]->distance;

}
```

Now, its possible to use qsort outside the iteration:

```
qsort(sl->city, sl->count, sizeof(City *), &citySort);
```

keep in mind that &citySort is the sort algorithm. This needs to defined seperated, based on what you want to sort. In my case:

```
int citySort(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    City *ba = *(City **)a;
    City *bb = *(City **)b;
    if (ba->distance > bb->distance)
        return +1;
    else if (ba->distance < bb->distance)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```